# Used .prop and now buttons not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quick question about JQuery's `prop()`. I used it for a check in an 'if' statement but now when I click on the `manualOverrideYes` radio button that it is connected to I can't click on a different button. Can anyone explain how I am using the `prop()` wrong? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks again!

HTML:

```
Manual Overide: 
        <label>No <input type="radio" name="manualOverride" id="manualOverrideNo" value="no" checked /></label>
        <label>Yes<input type="radio" name="manualOverride" id="manualOverrideYes" value="yes" /></label>

        <div id="manualOverrideWarning">test</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#manualOverrideYes, #manualOverrideNo').bind('change', function () {
    if($('#manualOverrideYes').prop('checked', true)) {
        $('#manualOverrideWarning').text('Auto-complete Disabled!');
    } else {
        ($('#manualOverrideWarning').text('Auto-complete Enabled'));
    }
});
```

Comment: You want: `if($('#manualOverrideYes').prop('checked'))` In modern browsers you could use: `if(manualOverrideYes.checked)`

Comment: `if($('#manualOverrideYes').prop('checked')) {` you were assigning in your IF statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `.prop()` method as a setter which returns a jQuery object and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript, you should use it as a getter which returns a boolean value in this case:

```
if ( $('#manualOverrideYes').prop('checked') ) { }
```

Alternatively you can also use the `.text()` method callback function instead of using `if` statement:

```
$('#manualOverrideYes, #manualOverrideNo').on('change', function () {
    $('#manualOverrideWarning').text(function() {
       return $('#manualOverrideYes').prop('checked')
              ? 'Auto-complete Disabled!'
              : 'Auto-complete Enabled';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this

```
if($('#manualOverrideYes').prop('checked', true)) {
```

should be this

```
if($('#manualOverrideYes').prop('checked')) {
```

---

When you pass just one value to `prop`, like this

```
$('#manualOverrideYes').prop('checked')
```

it returns the `checked` value back to you, which is what I think you want.  But when you pass a second parameter, then you're **setting** the property to that second value.  So this

```
$('#manualOverrideYes').prop('checked', true)
```

will *always* set the checked property to true, and then return the jQuery result set (which is always truthy).

The result is that when you run your if statement, the radio button will always become checked, and the if statement will always return true.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `is(':checked')`

```
$('#manualOverrideYes, #manualOverrideNo').bind('change', function () {
    if ($('#manualOverrideYes').is(':checked')){
        $('#manualOverrideWarning').text('Auto-complete Disabled!');
    } else {
        ($('#manualOverrideWarning').text('Auto-complete Enabled'));
    }
});
```